# Screw stuck in wood

Tags: carpentry

[image]

I can't get these two screws out and I've tried using a drill and a screw driver. Any tips?

Comment: Is the bit camming out of the head? Are the screws spinning freely in the wood?  Are you sure these aren't those pesky Pozi screws?

Answer (score 4):

It's readily apparent that you tried to use a drill.  The drill went "ratta-ratta-ratta-ratta" with lots of shaking.  Maybe you even think that's how drill-drivers normally work. Or maybe the last guy did that while initially driving it, because it's hard to stop the momentum of a spinning drill.  Which is why it now looks like a Posidriv screw head instead of a Phillips.

Use a manual screwdriver, and press **hard** down the handle while you turn, and don't let it cam out.

If you can't do that, do what I do -- get a [speed wrench](http://www.sears.com/craftsman-speeder-wrench-1-4-in-drive/p-00904281000P) and a [bit holder](http://amzn.to/1VmaSGs).  This lets you press really hard while giving a lot of leverage to turn. It also lets you turn really fast and stop on a dime.

[image]
[source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Speed_wrench.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get the screws to turn you just need to make sure that you're using a fresh #2 Phillips bit with the driver perfectly aligned with the screw, and press very firmly.

If the screws are spinning, it's probably because the threaded portion has gone beyond any firm material. Use a chisel or putty knife to pry up on the head of the screw while you spin it backwards with the drill, pressing lightly. Once the threads find their way out to solid wood the screw will back out easily.

Comment: Even if the threads of the screw never "find their way out to solid wood" the putty knife will suffice to give the screw something to rotate out from the wood.

Answer (score 1):

Use a small rotary tool (such as Dremel) and a cutoff disk (wear eye protection, and be aware of where the sparks are going so you don't start a fire) to cut a slot for a flat-bladed screwdriver. I think you've damaged the original sufficiently to make it dubious that you'll get them out with a Phillips, now.